# How do i pass a string using char into fopen C

Tags: c, fopen

I have tried using the following code to pass a char into a string and to open a .txt file so i can read it's content. I have no idea why and how can i utilize this fopen to actually read test.txt

```
int main(){

char input[60];


char a;
FILE *file;

printf("Hello!\n");

    enter code here

printf("Pelase input a file name in .txt format: \n");
gets(input);

printf("%s",input);
printf("\n");

**file = fopen("%c,input","rt");**
```

// file = fopen("%s",input) <-- Doesnt work

// file = fopen("%s",input,rt) <-- Error

```
if (file){

  while((a=fgetc(file))!=EOF){

        printf("%c",a);
    }
    fclose(file);


}
}
```

Comment: `fopen(input, "rt");`

Comment: You need to pass a pointer to the first element of a string with the name of the file you intend to open.

Comment: `char a;` should be `int a;` and don't use `gets` (one alternative is to use `fgets` and then remove the trailing newline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add `".txt"` to whatever the user entered, then open that file, you can use:

```
gets (input);
strcat (input, ".txt");
file = fopen (input, "r");
```

Note that I do *not* advocate the use of `gets`, or blindly appending to buffers without first checking the size, but this is the minimum necessary change to achieve what you want. See below for why those two things are a bad idea.

---

*Additional problems with the current code:*

- The return value from `fgetc()` is, and hence the type of `a` should be, `int`.
- The `gets()` function is inherently unsafe, to the point where it's been removed from the standard. Use `fgets()` or find a [safe user input function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921).
- Don't ever append to buffers blindly. Like the use of `gets()` and certain `scanf()` format strings, it will allow buffer overflows in your code.

Comment: can i know what "r" means? i have seen some samples using "w" some using "wr" and whats not

Comment: @user3809384: `"r"` is read only. Any good link on the net for `fopen()` should detail these. `"wr"` is short for "wrong way to do it" :-)